# preventDefault on tab keyboard event resets cursor position during continuous typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, gmail, preventdefault

tab keydown event with preventDefault resets cursor position to start when tab is the last in a series of continuous keystrokes

I've got a chrome gmail extension written in react where I'm overriding tab behavior. preventDefault and stopImmediatePropagation in the event listener seem to only work when tab is the only keyboard event clicked within a cursor blink. If tab is the last character pressed in a continuous series of keystrokes, the cursor resets to the start of the composed message although the event still has it's default prevented. This behavior is only for the tab key - for example the same event listener works correctly when preventing "q". Tab prevention only seems to work if I focus on the contentEditable after preventDefault

```
  public componentDidMount () {
    const { el } = this.props.editable;
    el.addEventListener("keydown", this.testKeys.bind(this), true);
  };

  private testKeys (e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.key === "Tab") {
      console.log("tab");
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      this.props.editable.el.focus();
    } 
  }
```

How do I keep the correct cursor position even when tab is the last of a series of key strokes?

Comment: you should get the caret position and reset to last position on tab press. google how to get caret position

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

Gmail attaches its own listener for the tab keydown event to preventDefault() and change the focus to the next element, at the the window level. To catch the event first you need to set your event listener on the window with capture:true.